# Как выделять изменяемый текст в textbox?

Tags: wpf

У меня есть следующее:

```
<ListBox x:Name="Repeater"                          
         Items="{Binding TreeRoot.VisibleChildren}" 
         SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}"/>

<StackPanel Margin="10">                                                      
    <vm:ReceivedApplicationMessageDetailsView                                 
        DataContext="{Binding SelectedItem.Details, ElementName=Repeater }" />
```

ReceivedApplicationMessageDetailsView:

```
<StackPanel Margin="10">                                                                                         
    <Label Content="Topic" FontWeight="Bold" />                                                                  
    <TextBox UseFloatingWatermark="False" assists:TextFieldAssist.Label="Topic" Text="{Binding Topic}"/>         
                                                                                                                 
        <Label Content="Header" FontWeight="Bold" />                                                             
                                                                                                                 
    <views:BufferInspectorView  DataContext="{Binding PayloadInspector}"/>                                       
                                                                                                                 
</StackPanel>
```

Проблема следующая: сеттер у SelectedItem постоянно вызывается, что соответственно вызывает изменение в textbox. Из-за этого не получается скопировать текст, выделение постоянно сбрасывается. Как это можно исправить?
Хочу видеть следующее поведение: значение в textbox меняется, но текст получается скопировать

Comment: Что-то мне кажется вы недорассказали. Не может просто так сеттер у SelectedItem постоянно вызываться. Может где триггер настроен на SelectedItem ? В сеттере у SelectedItem настроена проверка на null ? (if value != null)

Comment: @alex6327 вы были правы, сеттер не вызывается после добавления проверки, но проблема не решилась почему-то - окно с данными моргает, будто обновляется. Это странное поведение, т.к ничего не обновляется

Comment: я написал небольшой проект, демонстрирующий проблему. https://github.com/INTERNALINTERFERENCE/SelectionProblem